# How many 6 letter words can be made in English with at most 2 vowels?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many 6 letter words can be  made in English with ***at most*** 2 vowels?

Comment: I assume we are working orthographically, so that we have 5 vowels. (Random fact: American English has up to 11 phonologically distinct vowels. :) )

Comment: How many $6$ letter words have no vowels? How many have exactly one vowel? And how many have exactly two vowels? Then add these three numbers together.

Answer (score 1):

Divide the problem and solve it. First the English alphabet have 5 vowels and 21 consonant. Now back to the solution, we are checking special cases:

**Words containing now vowels**

Because there are 21 consonants and we need to make $6$ letter word the total number is:

$$21^{6} \text{words containing now vowels}$$

**Words containing 1 vowel**

In this case we have one place for vowel and we have 5 options, and for the consonant there are 5 places so we have: $5 \times 21^{5}$ words. But that's the number of words when the place of the vowel is fixed so because there are $6$ places multiply the number by $6$ and the total amount would be:

$$30 \times 21^5 \text{ words with only 1 vowel}$$

**Words containing 2 vowels**

Simularly as the previos case, except now we have 2 places for vowels and 4 for consonants an the totat amount would be: $5^2 \times 21^4$. But the 2 places can be anywhere in the words, so there are $\binom{6}{2} = 15$ places to place them. So the total amount would be:

$$15 \times 5^2 \times 21^4 \text{ words containg exactly 2 vowels}$$

Now just add all those numbers:

$$21^6 + 30 \times 21^5 + 15 \times 5^2 \times 21^4 = 21^4 (21^2 + 21 \times 30 + 15 \times 5^2) = 21^4 (441 + 630 + 375) = 281219526 \text{ words with at most 2 vowels}$$